# v-repeat in table rows

Tags: html, vue.js

I have table of emails with `<TR>`'s being repeated with `v-repeat` followed with a single `<TR>` for displaying an empty form for adding a new email.

Problem is that the `<TR>` with empty form always appears as the FIRST row BEFORE the list of existing email `<TR>`s.

Is there a way to force the `<TR>` with the empty email form to render AFTER the list of email `<TR>`'s?

```
<section v-show="emails" v-cloak>
    <table id="email-list">
        <tbody>
            <tr
                v-repeat="email: emails"
                class="email"
                v-class="
                    editing   : this == editedEmail
                "
            >
                <td>
                    <input
                        class   = "edit"
                        type    = "text"
                        v-model = "email.address | addressValidator"
                        v-on    = "
                            click : editAddress(this, $index),
                            blur  : doneEdit(this, $index),
                            keyup : doneEdit(this, $index) | key 'enter',
                            keyup : cancelEdit(this, $index) | key 'esc'
                        "
                    >
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a
                            class="btn btn-xs btn-danger"
                            style="cursor:pointer;"
                            v-on="click: removeEmail(this, $index)"
                            >
                        <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
                    </a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr
                class="email"
                v-class="
                    editing   : this == editedEmail
                "
            >
                <form
                    id="add-new-form"
                    v-on="submit:addNew"
                >
                    <input
                        id="0"
                        autofocus
                        autocomplete="off"
                        placeholder="New Email Address"
                        v-model="newEmail.address | addressValidator"
                    >


                    <button
                        type="submit"
                        v-show="newEmail.address && validation.address"
                        class="btn btn-xs btn-success"
                        style="cursor:pointer;"
                    >
                        <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                    </button>

                </form>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
</section>
```

Comment: Form cannot be a direct child of tr. Why not put the for outside of the table ?

Comment: Wow! Something so obvious!!! Actually, all I had to do is wrap the Form in a TD! :) Thank you.

Comment: You should better place the form outside of the table as it is not part of the datas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A form can’t be a direct child of a table row. Put it outside of the table as it is not part of the datas.

Answer (score 0):

@Samuel De Backer pointed out the problem in his comment to my question.